# Как кроссбраузерно установить автоматическое воспроизведение видео на сайте?

Tags: html, css, видео

Пытаюсь поставить видео. В хроме отображается, в IE9 и Safari - нет. К слову: Не ставлю controls (не нужны), но почему-то автоматически не воспроизводится, хотя аутоплей стоит. Эксперимента ради поставил контролс - видео запускается.

PS
Нафиг старьё! - не вариант.

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

<video class="video-1" width="450" height="280" preload="preload" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
  <source src="video/eshkere-450x280.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs="theora, vorbis"" />          
</video>
```

Comment: А почему в source что попало понаписано? В mp4 файлах не бывает ни theora, ни vorbis

Comment: что за кодек в контейнере mp4 ?

Comment: Кодек убрал. Ничего не изменилось

Comment: если кодек AVC то попробуйте полный путь указать для видео

Comment: Путь от корня ?

Comment: http://......video/eshkere-450x280.mp4

Comment: В итоге, код такой. В FF и IE9 работает, в Хроме и Сафари = отображается но не запускается: 

<div class="article--header-bg-photo">
                        <video class="video" width="450" height="280" preload="preload" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
                        <source src="video/eshkere-450x280.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                        
                        </video>
                    </div>

Comment: хром и сафари очень чуствительны к кодекам. а вы так и не написали чем закодирован mp4

Comment: В примере, который я видел, этот формат фигурирует без кодека, в отличие от других форматов

Comment: Ну вот прописал такой кодек: type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'

Comment: контейнер MP4 кодируется видеокодеком AVC (h264) и аудиокодеком AAC - к примеру. Что в примере кода - не важно. Я и спросил с начала с самого - какой кодек?

Comment: или скиньте  путь до файла доступный через веб сам посмотрю. или прямо попытайтесь открыть в  хроме/сафари путь с видео

Comment: как правильно прописываются упомянутые кодеки АVC(h264), AAC ?

Comment: их не надо прописывать.... ладно понятно все... закругляюсь